# Count all objects in array and infinite sub-arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "ArticleName": "Example Article",
    "Comments": [
        {
            "Text": "Great Article",
            "Responses": [
                {
                    "Text": "No it isnt",
                    "Responses": [
                        {
                            "Text": "Yes it is"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Text": "Spot on"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Every occurrence of the key 'Text' would be considered as a comment (so 4 comments). What's the best way to get a count on this in Mongo?

Comment: Is there any issue with the below answer

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I've rolled the question back to before you edited it. It needs to be a count on an infinite (hence the title) number of comments not just the ones I've shown in the example. So it needs to be a dynamic solution

Comment: It will count any number of comments. Check the mongoplayground link in the answer and edit your collection in the left hand side of the playground. It will count all the nested  comments.

Comment: You can check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lnJQoEXqBZt). I have added more nested comments. Now count changed

Comment: So it does @AnthonyWinzlet. Very good. I'll mark that correct. I just thought there'd be a nicer built in function to grab all this. I've since switched to a graph db but good to know

Comment: Aggregation is it self a function of mongodb and this is the best way to do this type of tricks.

Comment: I was thinking maybe a function like countAll('comments'), and mongo was able to identify the type from the json somehow. I'm just thinking out loud here. I've not really done anything with mongo. The aggregation solution feels a bit verbose. But then maybe storing this type of data isn't right in a non relational context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

Basically you have to loop over the each array using [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and count for the fields where `Text` is not equal to [**`$ne`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/) `undefined`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "commentsCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Comments",
          "as": "cc",
          "in": {
            "$add": [
              { "$cond": [{ "$ne": [ "$$cc.Text", undefined ] }, 1, 0 ] },
              { "$sum": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$cc.Responses",
                  "as": "dd",
                  "in": {
                    "$add": [
                      { "$cond": [{ "$ne": [ "$$dd.Text", undefined ] }, 1, 0 ] },
                      { "$sum": {
                        "$map": {
                          "input": "$$dd.Responses",
                          "as": "ee",
                          "in": { "$cond": [{ "$ne": [ "$$ee.Text", undefined ] }, 1, 0 ] }
                        }
                      }}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9mNQo66baCe)

```
[
  {
    "commentsCount": 4
  }
]
```